# password protect directory but still allow use on main page

Tags: php, file

I'm trying to move an image to a tmp directory on the server side and then send it to the client from the tmp folder, but things aren't quite working. Here's what I currently have.

```
//this is where the image resides permanently
$imgdirectory = "../" . $ms . "msimages/" . $img_filename;
//here I'm trying to get the contents of the img from its permanent location    
$content = file_get_contents($imgdirectory);
//here I'm trying to create a new temporary file
file_put_contents('/tmp/img.jpg', $content);

...

echo "img {background:url(\"/tmp/img.jpg\")-" . $xleft . "px -" . $ytop . "px";}"; this is the css trying to use file that is supposed to be in the temp folder
```

and here's the css output I get when the page loads

```
img#{width:631px;height:453px;background:url("/tmp/img.jpg")-144px -112px;}
```

But unfortunately, there is no file at `/tmp/img.jpg` so something must not quite be working with the `file_put_contents` `404 image not found`

btw, I'm not getting any errors about permissions to `put contents` in /tmp,

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: If you haven't given the script read permissions, or access permissions it may return file not found.

Answer (score 2):

Use copy instead of reading and writing files

```
 bool copy ( string $source , string $dest [, resource $context ] )
```

And

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/img.jpg', $content);
```

will put it under root tmp directory not in your sites tmp directory.

Try

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . 'tmp/img.jpg', $content);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Still not quite working -- but I think there are lot of factors causing problems for me. Copy seems like better route though -- I think my main problem is with permissions.